# Web scraping page with SelectorGadget

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I have my webpage here has simple element . I just want to web scrape the lower part of the data which comes in row (station information and sounding indices). However my SelectorGadget does not properly address the desired data, it keep showing upper part of the data. How this can be improved?

```
install.packages("rvest")
library(rvest)
sounding <- html("http://weather.uwyo.edu/cgi-bin/sounding?region=seasia&TYPE=TEXT%3ALIST&YEAR=2019&MONTH=01&FROM=2012&TO=2012&STNM=48615")
sounding %>%html_node("h3,pre") %>%html_text()
```

Answer (score 2):

## Original Answer

A different selector is what you want. Make sure that you eliminate all other "yellow" choices you *don't want* to scrape:

```r
library(rvest)
#> Loading required package: xml2
sounding <- read_html("http://weather.uwyo.edu/cgi-bin/sounding?region=seasia&TYPE=TEXT%3ALIST&YEAR=2019&MONTH=01&FROM=2012&TO=2012&STNM=48615")

sounding %>%
  html_nodes("h3+ pre") %>% 
  html_text()
#> [1] "\n                         Station identifier: WMKC\n                             Station number: 48615\n                           Observation time: 190120/1200\n                           Station latitude: 6.16\n                          Station longitude: 102.28\n                          Station elevation: 5.0\n                            Showalter index: 1.26\n                               Lifted index: -2.86\n    LIFT computed using virtual temperature: -3.38\n                                SWEAT index: 187.99\n                                    K index: 14.40\n                         Cross totals index: 19.00\n                      Vertical totals index: 23.90\n                        Totals totals index: 42.90\n      Convective Available Potential Energy: 409.13\n             CAPE using virtual temperature: 595.76\n                      Convective Inhibition: -26.90\n             CINS using virtual temperature: -8.60\n                           Equilibrum Level: 228.72\n Equilibrum Level using virtual temperature: 226.79\n                   Level of Free Convection: 819.49\n             LFCT using virtual temperature: 871.25\n                     Bulk Richardson Number: 240.00\n          Bulk Richardson Number using CAPV: 349.48\n  Temp [K] of the Lifted Condensation Level: 294.55\nPres [hPa] of the Lifted Condensation Level: 938.33\n     Mean mixed layer potential temperature: 299.97\n              Mean mixed layer mixing ratio: 17.45\n              1000 hPa to 500 hPa thickness: 5782.00\nPrecipitable water [mm] for entire sounding: 46.56\n"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

## Updated Answer

Went back through and cleaned up into a table that resembles that table found on the website. I'm sure it could be more elegantly done but that should suffice to get it into table format.

```r
library(rvest)
#> Loading required package: xml2
library(tidyverse)
sounding <- read_html("http://weather.uwyo.edu/cgi-bin/sounding?region=seasia&TYPE=TEXT%3ALIST&YEAR=2019&MONTH=01&FROM=2012&TO=2012&STNM=48615")

raw_dat <- sounding %>%
  html_nodes("h3+ pre") %>% 
  html_text()

raw_dat %>% 
  str_split(pattern = "\n", simplify = T) %>% 
  map_chr(str_squish) %>% 
  tibble(x = .) %>% 
  separate(x, into = c("Station", "Value"), sep = ": ") %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Value))
#> Warning: Expected 2 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 2 rows [1,
#> 32].
#> # A tibble: 30 x 2
#>    Station                                 Value      
#>    <chr>                                   <chr>      
#>  1 Station identifier                      WMKC       
#>  2 Station number                          48615      
#>  3 Observation time                        190120/1200
#>  4 Station latitude                        6.16       
#>  5 Station longitude                       102.28     
#>  6 Station elevation                       5.0        
#>  7 Showalter index                         1.26       
#>  8 Lifted index                            -2.86      
#>  9 LIFT computed using virtual temperature -3.38      
#> 10 SWEAT index                             187.99     
#> # … with 20 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: can you advice how should I edit this further on so I can get value by call their variables name

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean. Can you give me an example?

Comment: I wish I can transform the product into list/data frame (?) with their variable name. so I can navigate through each variable by calling  'raw_data $ SWEAT index'

Comment: `indices <- raw_dat %>% 
  str_split(pattern = "\n", simplify = T) %>% 
  map_chr(str_squish) %>% 
  tibble(x = .) %>% 
  separate(x, into = c("Station", "Value"), sep = ": ") %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Value))`
now the available variables only either 'indices$station' and 'indices$value'